# Interrupting blocking calls from parallel thread

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading

The simple code below exemplifies a problem I'm having waking a thread that is blocking on a driver call.  I don't have the driver source code, but need to wake the thread to shut down the process if the physical device that the driver is blocking on has a power interruption.

Example (see code below):

`main()` sets up a signal handler for `SIGINT`, launches a child thread and then goes into an infinite loop where it repeatedly sleeps, wakes and prints out when it awoke.  The child thread does the same thing, but each time it wakes, it also sends a `SIGINT` to the process.  `sleep()` is used as a simple blocking call.

Running the code shows the following behavior:

- Each time the child thread wakes, it print it's 'When' message (when it awoke).  Then the signal handler reports that it received the `SIGINT`.
- Each time 'main' wakes, it print it's 'When' message.

as follows:

```
main: 0.127

Child: 0.127

SignalHandler: signum = 2

Child: 5.127

SignalHandler: signum = 2

main: 7.127

Child: 10.127

SignalHandler: signum = 2

main: 14.127

Child: 15.128

SignalHandler: signum = 2

Child: 20.128

SignalHandler: signum = 2

main: 21.127

.
.
.
```

I expected that as a result of the `SIGINT` being received by the process, `main()` would break out of it's blocking call to `sleep()`.  This would be seen as `main()` printing it's 'When' message.  In fact this is exactly the behavior that I see if I type <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> (`SIGINT`) from the shell.  You can see two <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> interruptions below.  Each time, `main()` does indeed break out of it's blocking call to `sleep()`:

```
main: 0.417

child: 0.417

SignalHandler: signum = 2

child: 5.417

SignalHandler: signum = 2

^C

SignalHandler: signum = 2

main: 6.664

child: 10.417

SignalHandler: signum = 2

main: 13.664

child: 15.418

SignalHandler: signum = 2

^C

SignalHandler: signum = 2

main: 16.680

child: 20.418

SignalHandler: signum = 2

main: 23.680

child: 25.418

SignalHandler: signum = 2
```

----------- The Code ---------------

```
// Compile using:
//   g++ Test.cpp -o Test -g -lpthread -lrt

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include  <time.h>

void When(const char *who) {
  timespec sTimespec;
  static long startSecond = -1;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &sTimespec);

  if (startSecond == -1)
    startSecond = sTimespec.tv_sec;

  sTimespec.tv_sec -= startSecond;
  sTimespec.tv_nsec /= 1e+6; // only show milliseconds
  printf("%s: %ld.%03ld\n", who, sTimespec.tv_sec, sTimespec.tv_nsec);
}

void SignalHandler(int signum) {
  printf("SignalHandler: signum = %d\n", signum);
}

void *Child(void *pContext) {
  char temp[256];

  for (;;) {
    When("Child");
    kill(getpid(), SIGINT);
    sleep(5);
  } 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  pthread_t childThread; 

  signal(SIGINT, SignalHandler);
  pthread_create(&childThread, NULL, Child, NULL); 

  for (;;) {
    When("main");
    sleep(7);
  }  

  return 0;
}
```

So it seems like when a process sends `SIGINT` to itself, the signal gets delivered (see first results), but blocking calls are not interrupted.  Sending `SIGINT` from an external process delivers the signal and the blocking call gets interrupted.

Other things I've tried:

```
raise(SIGINT);

pthread_kill(mainThreadId, SIGINT); // where mainThreadId is resolved to pthread_self() from within 'main'

sprintf(temp, “kill -2 %d”, getpid()); system(temp);
```

I wrote a standalone program (xkill) that takes a pid as an argument and sends `SIGINT` to that PID.

Then:

```
sprintf(temp, “xkill %d”, getpid()); system(temp);
```

Note: I can run this program from a shell and get the good/expected behavior.

It seems to me that no child (thread or process) can interrupt a blocked call in its parent, even though it can deliver a signal.

Can one of you shed some light on this situation?

For my real code, I need to programmatically  break the blocking driver call out, so I can shutdown cleanly.  In my real code, the child thread is a device health monitor.

Comment: Just arrange things so that the thread will only do harmless things when it breaks out of the function, perhaps by checking a cancel flag on return from the function and setting that cancel flag. Then you don't have to care whether the thread breaks out of the function or not.

Comment: Any thread in a process may be used to deliver the signal; a blocking call is only interrupted if a signal is delivered to that same thread. (Even if the signal handler has an empty body.) So, you need to either block the signal in all threads except the one that you wish interrupted (that does the blocking call), or you can use a signal handler that forwards the signal to the desired thread (unless already caught by the desired thread). Paul Griffiths answered with a pretty good example of the latter already, although I guess an even simpler/more straightforward example would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

With a few small modifications, seems to work as you desire at my end (Debian Linux - if I take out the `clock_gettime()` stuff it works the same way on Mac OS X, too) with `pthread_kill()`:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

void When(const char *who) {
    struct timespec sTimespec;
    static long startSecond = -1;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &sTimespec);

    if (startSecond == -1) {
        startSecond = sTimespec.tv_sec;
    }

    sTimespec.tv_sec -= startSecond;
    sTimespec.tv_nsec /= 1e+6;  // only show milliseconds
    printf("%s: %ld.%03ld\n", who, sTimespec.tv_sec, sTimespec.tv_nsec);
}

void SignalHandler(int signum) {
    printf("SignalHandler: signum = %d\n", signum);
}

void *Child(void *pContext) {
    pthread_t * main_tid = pContext;

    while ( true ) {
        When("Child");
        pthread_kill(*main_tid, SIGINT);
        sleep(5);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t childThread;

    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = SignalHandler;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("thread: couldn't set SIGINT handler");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };

    pthread_t own_tid = pthread_self();
    pthread_create(&childThread, NULL, Child, &own_tid);

    while ( true ) {
        When("main");
        sleep(7);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ gcc -o thread thread.c -pthread -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -lpthread -lrt
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./thread
main: 0.464
Child: 0.464
SignalHandler: signum = 2
main: 0.464
Child: 5.464
SignalHandler: signum = 2
main: 5.464
Child: 10.464
SignalHandler: signum = 2
main: 10.464
Child: 15.464
SignalHandler: signum = 2
main: 15.465
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./thread
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ kill %1

[1]+  Stopped                 ./thread
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```